# Microwave oven first time use — "10 minutes with water"?

Tags: microwave

My Samsung ME731K microwave oven just arrived. There is this instruction (in less than perfect English) and I'm not sure how to interpret it.

> Before using the your oven first time, oven should be operated with the water during 10 minute and then used.

Does it mean I should put a bowl of water inside and let the oven run for 10 minutes?

Comment: That is just odd but what could it hurt? Go with a decent sized bowl or will bill boil.   I am think a quart but that is just a guess.

Comment: I don't know about first use ... but doing it helps loosen stuff off the inside of the microwave after a food explosion.  (although I normally just do 3-5 minutes, not 10)

Comment: What CAN hurt is trying to dispose of a bowl of superheated water afterwards....

Answer (score 12):

The directions are in fact asking you to place a bowl of water in the Microwave Oven and run it for 10mins.

The reason is, it allows things to "break-in" and assures that you don't have any direct issues with the device and that all nasty solvents are given proper time to "burn off." This is so you don't end up with nasty plastic smells and flavors in your first meal.

**For safety reasons, I would recommend placing a wooden spoon in the bowl. This provides plenty of nucleations sites and will prevent "super-heating" of the water.**

Always use microwave appropriate containers, and allow the bowl to come to reasonable (warm to room temp) prior to handling.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, that's what it will mean.  Put a bowl of water in the microwave and heat on normal high setting for the 10 minutes.  Ensure that the bowl you use is glass or ceramic certified heat proof for the oven and be careful how you handle the bowl once it has finished as it will be hotter than you think!  You will end up with the whole microwave covered in condensed water which you can just wipe down.

Possibly this is their way of ensuring that any residual dust, etc., is cleared from the microwave before it is first used.  This is also a useful way to clean your microwave if you get any burnt on food during use.  But you wouldn't have to do it for 10 minutes then.  Just long enough to loosen the burnt on food - possibly 2-3 minutes.

Comment: There's going to be dust and junk in there from the sea voyage on the container ship. 10 min of humidity and fan should knock it down, and likely blow it out of oven.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how dangerous, but I have been told that running a microwave without anything in it can be dangerous. So, as pointed out, maybe the first ten minute run loosens up the moving parts. They suggest water, just because you can throw it out immediately, and on the cheap.

Answer (score -1):

New microwave oven Just ask you to boil a cup of water. 4-5mins

I try that for 4:30min and the water is bubbling boil. I guess they ask you to so that for seasoning the nachine so that it run smoothly and cleaner when you use it. maybe to smoothen out the oil or motor, belt, pulley but that just my opinions

Comment: Those are not things that would be accomplished by boiling water.